# Can Qt menu bar be queried for menu entries?

Tags: qt, menu, menuitem

Can Qt build menu bars with a widget that allows to write the menu entry to select, and the menu bar tries to guess what the user is looking for providing a list of candidate entries?

I am sure this can be implemented manually, but I am wondering if this is a feature that Qt provides out of the box.

See the image for an example (from Visual Studio 2022).

[image]

Comment: This is available by default out-of-the-box on macOS is you are using native menu. On Windows and Linux you have to develop it yourself.

Comment: @V.K. - Do you mean it is available in the macOS version of Qt, or in macOS itself?

Comment: I believe it is a part of macOS, see e.g. https://www.macrumors.com/how-to/use-the-macos-help-menu/